# Qual o padrão para nomeação de módulos (fontes) em Python?

Tags: python, design-pattern

Em Java temos o costume de criar fontes com a primeira letra maiúscula por exemplo: `Carrinho.java` e `DetalheCompraFragment.java`.

Porém até o momento não encontrei um padrão para nomeação de módulos em Python.

Recentemente vi arquivos com esses formatos: `detalhe_compra.py`, `detalhecompra.py`, `DetalheCompra.py`, `DETALHECOMPRA.py`.

Isto posto, fica a dúvida: **No Python existe um padrão ou o desenvolvedor escolhe como irá nomear?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sim. O Python possui vários guias de estilo denominados PEP (Python Enhancement Proposals). Em particular, o [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) traz detalhes sobre como nomear corretamente cada tipo de identificador.

Lê-se:

> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability.

Ou, em tradução livre:

> *Módulos devem ter nome curtos e em minúsculas. Underscores (`_`) podem ser usados no nome do módulo se isso melhorar a legibilidade.*

Portanto, `detalhecompra.py` e `detalhe_compra.py` são os dois nomes permitidos pelo Guia de Estilos.

### Classes

Para classes, no entanto, a regra é diferente. O mesmo documento traz o seguinte:

> Class names should normally use the CapWords convention.
>
> The naming convention for functions may be used instead in cases where the interface is documented and used primarily as a callable.

Ou, em tradução livre:

> *Nomes de classes devem, normalmente, usar a convenção CapWords (ou PascalCase).*
>
> *A convenção de nomenclatura para funções pode ser usada em casos nos quais a interface é documentada e utilizada principalmente como um* callable.

Então é comum ter um arquivo `detalhe_compra.py` que contém a classe `DetalheCompra`. A importação fica assim:

```py
from detalhe_compra import DetalheCompra
```

Isso, é claro, também acontece nas stdlibs:

```py
from typing import NewType
```

Comment: Héliton, muito obrigado pela resposta, mas ainda estou com uma dúvida. Este mesmo padrão se aplica quando estamos falando de classes?

Comment: @GuilhermeBigois, adicionei a parte sobre classes :)